# Creating nav bar with dropdowns using bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I couldn't find a straight answer.

I am new to css and jQuery and I'm trying to create a nav bar that has menus and sub menus, and using dropdown to open each **individual menu**.

This might be a parent/child issue but I can't figure out how to select just one menu to drop-down with jQuery, because right now **all** the menus open on hover.

What am I doing wrong? appreciate your help!

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href=# class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">sub menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub menu2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href=# class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">sub menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub menu2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href=# class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu3</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">sub menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub menu2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var main = function() {

$('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
}); }$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing

```
$('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
```

You're targetting all the elements that match the selector - all your dropdown menus.

What you need to do is:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

So first we select hovered element (`$(this)`), then travel up the DOM tree to `<li class="dropdown">` (`.parent()`), and within it we find .dropdown-menu (`.find('.dropdown-menu')`).

Also, consider binding the function to `<li class="dropdown">`. This way, the menu won't disappear when you move your mouse down on `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`. This is because when you hover `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` you also hover its parent, `<li class="dropdown">`, and you probably don't want to hide your sub-menu just because you don't hover your menu title anymore.

A side note, but important: Please don't forget to add `aria-haspopup="true"` to your `<li class="dropdown">` elements for enhanced accessibility and touch support.

Comment: I figured out the all element targeting part but didn't know how select one element. Worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will also make sure your dropdown doesn't disappear until they actually leave the main .dropdown LI

```
var main = function() {

$('.dropdown').hover(function() {

    //on hover
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).toggle();
}, function() {

     //on mouseout
     $('.dropdown-menu', this).toggle();
}); }$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Buwm8/)**.

```
<!-- Parent Menu -->
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="parentMenu"
    role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>

    <!-- Child Menu -->
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>

            <!-- Grandchild Menu -->
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#">More..</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And if you don't want it to begin displaying until click; simply `display:none;` in the css of menu wrapper. And then create a click function to show.

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#parentMenu" ).show( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

and:

```
<div id="clickme">Wanna see me cool menu?</div>
<!-- full menu mark up below here -->
```